# I can not draw a rectangle on the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

When I press the button "Draw". I can't draw rectangle on image.

https://jsfiddle.net/ikat/5xzc13r9/

```
function drawRect() {
// creating a square
var w = endX - startX;
var h = endY - startY;
var offsetX = (w < 0) ? w : 0;
var offsetY = (h < 0) ? h : 0;
var width = Math.abs(w);
var height = Math.abs(h);

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(startX + offsetX, startY + offsetY, width, height);
ctx.lineWidth = 7;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}
```

Comment: The reason nothing happens is because you are calling the wrong function. You have in HTML `<input onclick="initDraw()"...`   there is no function named `initDraw`.   Also the function `drawSquare` will not draw until after you select the image, this is because it need the coords of the square from the mouse events and the mouse events are set up in the `handleFiles` function. Even then you need to set the square using the mouse else the `drawSquare` tries to draw at NaN which will not work.  To help locate bugs like this use devTools (hit F12 in your browser).